# After 'cordova platform update ios', the plugins not found

Tags: ios, cordova, plugins

When I build a Cordova app in iOS platform, I found a serious problem:

When I run the `command cordova platform update ios`, I found that the plugins were disappeared.

As you can see, the plugins are not in the 'Compile Sources', and the error

> CDVPlugin class CDVFile (pluginName: File) does not exist

is showed.

How should I solve this problem?

Cordova version: 7.0.1

node version: v6.10.3

[image: The problem you can see]

Answer (score 0):

Have exactly the same issue. 
My current workaround is to remove and add ios platform

```
cordova platform rm ios
cordova platform add ios
```

Comment: That's not an answer - this response belongs in a comment